# how can i add jars to lib folder in MyEclipse2013

Tags: myeclipse

I tried myeclipse2013 ,it seems that we cannot add jars to WEB-INF/lib,but if i do not add jars to this folder,there will be errors at running.

Comment: What problems are you facing while adding jars to this folder? Please make it clearer.

Comment: I just update myeclipse version, the problem is that if i add jars by this way: Myeclipse-project facets-(hibernate && spring), it seems ok, but errors occurred when starting tomcat,java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;the project is ok in 10-version with jars in lib folder. is that the  jars must be added in lib folder? but there is no choice in 13-version. I cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries on the build path are, by default, added to your lib folder during deployment (previous releases also did this, though you can always add jars to the lib folder in any release). Can you look at the deployment location to see if they are there? If not, the only reason I can think of is that your deployment assembly has somehow been altered. Right click on the project and select Properties. Now go to the MyEclipse->Deployment Assembly page to check that the libraries are listed and are deployed to the correct folder.

Comment: Thanks for the thanks but read this stackoverflow FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers You should thank responders by accepting their answer or marking it up as useful.